# KeyError from configparser.py when executing Twitter Bot

Tags: python, twitter, bots, keyerror, reply

I tried to make a Twitter bot from https://github.com/joaquinlpereyra/twitterImgBot

The installations went well and successfully but the problem came when I tried to execute it.

Below is the code for my config in the `config.py`.
Keys and Tokens removed with the API key replaced with random numbers because that's the problem I'm trying to address.

```
import os
import configparser
import tweepy

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
# read configs from file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(dname + '/settings')
twitter_config = config['Twitter']
api_key = twitter_config['2931928391273123']
secret_key = twitter_config['REMOVED']
token = twitter_config['REMOVED']
secret_token = twitter_config['REMOVED']
```

The error I'm getting when executing it in `cmd` is:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>cd C:\Documents and Settings\Administrat
or\Desktop\twitterImgBot-master

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\twitterImgBot-    master>python twitterbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterbot.py", line 3, in <module>
 from settings import config
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\twitterImgBot-master\settings\config.py", line 13, in <module>
api_key = twitter_config['2931928391273123']
File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 1203, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '2931928391273123'

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\twitterImgBot-master>
```

I looked up all the questions here that has something to do with `KeyError` but none of them have something to do with the Twitter's API key

Again, the API key which is `2931928391273123` is just a random number to substitute the original one for obvious reasons. I did double check it to make sure I had the correct keys/tokens before resorting to here.

This is also a first for me, so I'm hoping someone can lend me a helping hand! I would have posted the 2 screenshots of the Python file and the `cmd` but I'm only limited to one link.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you print the config dictionary to check what keys do you have?

Comment: @lapinkoira Thanks for the quick reply, but how do I check that? It doesn't make sense to me that API keys has something to do with the config dictionary. If it's any help, here're the two screenshots that I never got my chance to post in my question. http://imgur.com/a/hNPVB

Comment: What I mean is, you are loading a configuration file from /settings and that configuration file is parsed into a dictionary. IF you receive a KeyError it doesnt have anything to do with Twitter, it just mean the setting value doesnt appear in the file, can I see an example of the setting file?